# Would samples be considered data redundancy if they are similar to each other fairly naturally?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am working on building ML/DL solution for a problem where that data is considered, naturally similar and I am worried if that would be considered as data redundancy.

My question is, is that so? and if yes what can I do about this then, since this is a feature of the actual real data?

Answer (score 1):

Im no expert, but if this is a feature of real data then you shouldn't really worry.

If you want to do something about this, then maybe try to use some dimension reduction techniques, such as PCA (principle component analysis) which is known to reduce redundancy in the data if used correctly.